# Is the set of real numbers between 0 and 1 which only have 1 and 5 in their decimal representation, closed?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Q) $A$ is a set of real numbers between $0$ and $1$ which only have $1$ and $5$ in decimal representation. That is,

$A = \{x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \times1/10^n) \in [0,1] : a_n \in \{1, 5 \}, n = 1, 2, \ldots \}$.

Is A a closed and compact set? Does it have isolated point? Can $A$ contain interval?

My idea : As $A$ is a bounded , if $A$ is a closed set, $A$ is a compact set too. In addition to this, if we can prove $A$ is countable, A would have isolated point based on theorem that countable closed set has isolated point. And if $A$ is countable, it could not contain interval.

Sorry for writing only short and abstract idea, but this is my wits' end. Please help me find out answers.

Answer (score 0):

A is uncountable, has empty interior and no isolates.  To the point 0.1111.... the point 0.111...2111... is arbitrarly close as is 0.111...5111....

Yes it is closed.  From unit interval take (0.0, 0.1), (0.1, 0.5) and (0.5, 1,0).  Then continue taking (0.10, 0.11) etc like the middle third removal for the Cantor set.  In fact, is not A homeomorphic to the Cantor set?

Comment: Do you mean there exists a one to one function between $A$ and cantor set, and we can infer the properties of $A$ from cantor set?

Comment: All not empty perfect  2nd countable compact zero dimensional T0 spaces are homoemorphic.  Both the Cantor set and A are such.  A bijection would be digit by digit mapping sum_j  aj/10^j to sum_j bj/3^j where bj = 0 if aj  = 1,        = 3 if aj = 5.